# \hfill in in table cells

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, tabularx

There are tables in my document. The baselines between the last row of each table and the following text is usually circa `16,25p` (see below). Now I wanted to add right-aligned text to some selected one-line rows (`EXPLANATION IN COL2`).

I tried it two ways (using packages `calc` and `tabularx`; see below) but this seems to change the `16,25p` space. How can I maintain `16,25p` space?

I would like to retain two columns because some text from later rows may go beyond where `EXPLANATION IN COL2` starts. My preference would be the approach using `calc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{75pt}@{}@{}l@{}}
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT\\
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT
\end{tabular}
\vspace{5pt}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem.\vspace{30pt}\par

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{75pt}@{}@{}p{\textwidth-75pt}@{}}
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT \hfill EXPLANATION IN COL2\\
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT
\end{tabular}
\vspace{5pt}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem.\vspace{30pt}\par

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{75pt}@{}@{}X@{}}
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT \hfill EXPLANATION IN COL2\\
COL1TEXT & COL2TEXT
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{5pt}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always best to add vertical space in vertical mode so

```
\par\vspace{5pt}
```

not

```
\vspace{5pt}\par
```

also although it does no harm `@{}@{}` is rather odd markup you only need one: `@{}`.